# JQuery function to operate multiple divs

Tags: php, jquery

I'm writing a booking system in PHP and MySQL and the way that a user books a specific time slot is by clicking the Div which operates a JQuery function as you can see below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('.free').click(function(){
                    $(this).html("<div class='title'><img src='images/loader.gif' alt='image' width='30' /></div>").load('book.php?desk_id=<?php echo $desk_id;?>&booking_id='+this.id);
                });
                $('#bookweek').click(function(){
                    $('.free').html("<div class='title'><img src='images/loader.gif' alt='image' width='30' /></div>").load('book.php?desk_id=<?php echo $desk_id;?>&booking_id='+this.id);
                });
            })
```

What I am trying to do is get the second half of it where it would book the entire week to work. It partially works but doing a bit of investigation shows that it is not passing on the Div's ID in the URL, so obviously it's not passing on the correct variables to book.php which is making it not work.

There are many Divs with class 'free' but each has its own seperate ID. Any help on how to pass the individual IDs on in a URL would be greatly appreciated,

Many many thanks,

Steve

Edit:

The calender is generated using the following code:

```
<div id="bookweek" style="cursor:pointer"><h1>Book Entire Week</h1></div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="title">Times</div>
    <?php
$days = 0;
while($days < 7) {
    $day  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),   date("d") + $days,   date("Y"));
    $days++;
    echo '<div class="title">'.date("D d/m/y", $day).'</div>
    ';
}
?>
</div>
<?php
$hours = 0;
$counter = 0;
while($hours < count($bookingTimes)) {
    $name = $bookingTimes[$hours];
    $hours++;
    echo '<div class="block">
<div class="title">'.$name.'</div>
';
$i=0;
$counter++;
$days = 0;
while($i < 7) {
    $day  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"),   date("d") + $days,   date("Y"));
    $days++;
    $i++;
    $id = $counter + $day;
    echo '<div class="free" id="'.$id.'">'.checkBooked($id,$desk_id).'</div>
    ';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: try http://api.jquery.com/attr/  $('.free').attr('id');

Comment: @Waygood $(".free").attr("id") will get the id of the first element that has the `free` class. `this.id` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @steve what do you wish to pass? a list of id's? or what.

Comment: @Kevin - http://zykatious.dlinkddns.com/desk/desk.php?desk_id=36726
There's a live version, there'll be some bugs cause I disabled the auth so you can see what I mean. When you click Book Whole Week, I want it to trigger every cell to book themselves.

Comment: What you need to do is a bit more complex. Once you've added the nodes you need to add listeners to them so that they return their own id. The solution you're trying i.e. add innerHTML is inelegant and hard to manipulate.

Comment: As it stand now `$('.free')` is calling every div with class `free`. Is that desired or do you only want a specific set? This question could really use more information.

Comment: @Steve your current code doesn't do anything near what you are trying to do. The second half of your code would need to at least trigger the click handler on all .free elements. They will all get sent to the server, however only the last one to complete (not necessarily the last one in the list) will be the one that gets displayed to the user.

Comment: You can probably use your method by making a separate function that is called onclick - make the link href="javascript:my_func(this)". It's ugly but it should work.

Comment: @SpYk3HH I do indeed want it to call every div with the class free :)

Comment: We need to see the layout of the html, as we're currently just guessing how it's structured.

Comment: Updated with it, also you can see it live on http://zykatious.dlinkddns.com/desk/desk.php?desk_id=36726 if you want to see the generated html from php

Comment: @KevinB - $('.free').click can use this.id as this is the id of .free, BUT #bookweek shouldn't use this.id as this would be the id of #bookweek and not .free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for the click event handler for `#bookweek`

```
$("#bookweek").on("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".free").trigger("click")
});
```

It finds the parent div (the week) and then triggers a click event on each of the child elements with class `free`.

Comment: This works great, too... I'm not sure which one is best to use... They work identically :P

Comment: I did it this way so that you only have one place where you handle `.free` being clicked, so if you ever change the code for it then you only have to change it in one place.

Comment: You know you're right, this is my preferred answer. I don't need to change the page in any way, works right out of the box. Thanks, Archer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following. It should solve your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.free').click(function(){
                $(this).html("<div class='title'><img src='images/loader.gif' alt='image' width='30' /></div>").load('book.php?desk_id=<?php echo $desk_id;?>&booking_id='+this.id);
            });
            $('#bookweek').click(function(){
                $(this).find('.free').each(function () {
                       $(this).html("<div class='title'><img src='images/loader.gif' alt='image' width='30' /></div>").load('book.php?desk_id=<?php echo $desk_id;?>&booking_id='+this.id);
                });
            });
        })
```

Comment: Hey TapanC, This unfortunately does not work :( Nothing happens when I click the bookweek div.

Comment: In above code you may just replace `this.id` with `$(this).attr('id')` and it will work... just missed that!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bookweek').click(function() {
    $('.free').each(function() {
        var $id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).html("<div class='title'><img src='images/loader.gif' alt='image' width='30' /></div>")
                .load('book.php?desk_id=<?php echo $desk_id;?>&booking_id=' + $id);

    });
});
```

Comment: Beautiful, works exactly like I wanted it to, thank you very much :)

Comment: That will book both this week and next

Comment: You're right, Archer. Haha, I'll do a bit of change to compensate for that.

Comment: @Steve - see my answer below.  I tested it on your site and it works.